# How can i change the int array to string

Tags: c#

I have an `int` array that i want to display in a text box as follows, `(5 4 2 8 6)`. Please help me.

Comment: Are you working in C# or Java?  We can't tell.

Comment: @user1781384, So you're looking for both a C# solution and a Java solution??

Comment: no i answered in general  i want c# solution

Comment: @user1781384, Then next time, don't tag `java`!!!!!!!

Comment: but i want to know the solution in java too ,for the next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using C#:

```
TextBox.Text = string.Format("({0})", string.Join(" ", arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

For Java, you can use [`Arrays.toString(int[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29).

Comment: I've never heard of the `Arryas` object...also, please link to the latest javadoc (i.e. Java 7).

Comment: `Arryas` was a typo (corrected now), it is `Arrays`.  [Java 7 Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: I meant for you to edit your own answer, not to provide the link as a comment. And I don't believe this solution will work, since the returned string comma-delimits the integers.

Comment: It's is fairly easy to take the result and replace the commas and the   square brackets. If you don't like it: take a StringBuilder and a for loop.

Comment: @Andreas_D, Yes it is easy, but this answer makes it seem like this will be done right out of the box.